# How to create backup .bak file of specific table from database in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to restore new database in my Sql server but need one table from previous database.So I need to create a backup file of specific table so I can restore it in newer version of database.

Comment: Does it need to be a .bak? It would be probably be easier to generate SQL data+schema scripts for your one table.

Comment: http://www.sqlserver-training.com/how-to-backup-sql-table/-

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar Did you find a solution? I am in a similar boat.. I need to backup logs from prod .. each table has 250 million records and need data from few tables. The complete backup is almost 1TB; I don't want the full backup due to space (needs double space for backup & restore)

Comment: Hi, This issue I faced way long back, I did not remember exact solution to solve this problem. I would suggest try out @AkshayBheda 's or Mateo's solution. If it did not help comment on his answer. Or you can raise new question on this community. For now sorry I can't help you here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate Scripts for Schema and Data for that particular table. There are many tools available. You can use SSMS for that. 
After you have the table schema and the data you can run that script on the new database.

Answer (score 1):

To back up a database:

1. After connecting to the appropriate instance of the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine, in Object Explorer, click the server name to expand the server tree.
2. Expand Databases, and depending on the database, either select a user database or expand System Databases and select a system database.
3. Right-click the database, point to Tasks, and then click Back Up. The Back Up Database dialog box appears.
4. In the Database list box, verify the database name. You can optionally select a different database from the list.
5. You can perform a database backup for any recovery model (FULL, BULK_LOGGED, or SIMPLE).
6. In the Backup type list box, select Full.
7. Optionally, you can select Copy Only Backup to create a copy-only backup. A copy-only backup is a SQL Server backup that is independent of the sequence of conventional SQL Server backups.

These are the most important points, the other ones are very intuitive. For more details about here's a link that explain step by step how to create a backup (.bak) for your database.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx

Comment: Not specific to a single table as the original question asked.